# Is there any way to "emulate" a faster processor for a java application?

Tags: java, performance, processor

I know this is a little awkward question and may not even java dependent.

I have a java application that produces output at fixed time points, let's say at 50 seconds. The problem is the output heavily depends on the performance of the PC that is running the code.

For better reproducibility I want to "emulate" a faster processor and the code should return the outputs that would be calculated in 50 seconds on the faster processor. I know that this would actually take longer than the given time.

Is there any way to calculate the "actions" made of a certain processor speed? 
Would it be appropriate to calculate: (core speed of emulated Processor)/(core speed of actual Processor) * timeslices?

For example:
Emulated Processor 4GHz -> 50 sec == Actual Processor 2GHz -> 100 sec

Would snapshots with the actual processor lets say at 100 sec be the same as a snapshot at 50 sec with the emulated processor?

If this would be correct, there would be another problem. If the user that is running the code, would use the processor in another way, the outcome would also be falsified.

Comment: It's heavily, heavily dependent on what your application actually does. 2X clock speed hardly ever translates into 2X speedup -- applications often spend a lot of time waiting for disk and network operations to complete; multi-processing and multi-threading parallelization complicate the effect of clock speed boosts.

Comment: If you're pretending the program is running faster than it is, that's false also. Sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from a rigged demo.

Comment: Add to that processor features, such as cache, better branch prediction, more cores etc. The best way to verify is to actually run on a faster system. A cloud VM could be a cheap way to rent such a CPU only for the duration of the test.

Comment: The application is a link prediction algorithm for large knowledge graphs. So it is purely offline, and only reads and writes from/to disk at the beginning and the end. There is some parallelization, but you can specify how many threads are started as an argument.

Comment: I dont want to pretend that the program is running faster for a rigged demo :D I just want to add better reproducabilty to the algorithm, so that someone who has a less performant PC gets nearly the same results as someone who has a fast PC.